# OpenShift deployment process fails after enabling JENKINS

Tags: openshift

I created Tomcat 7 app in the OpenShift and enabled Jenkins (Jenkins server app was created and cartridge Jenkins was added to my app).

However, after calling git push, the deplpyment process does not complete successfully. In logs there is an error:

```
Caught com.openshift.client.OpenShiftException: Could not locate application with UUID ...
```

Has anyone of you experienced such a problem?

Comment: Did you do the app creation & enable jenkins in one step through the web console? Or did you create your application and then add jenkins later? (that info will help us troubleshoot it)

Comment: In the situation I described above I enabled JENKINS for already existed application. Today I deleted the app and created again already with JENKINS. After that the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like deleting the application and then re-creating it with jenkins enabled should fix that issue.  If you can re-produce the issue, the best thing would be to log a ticket with openshift here in their bugzilla tracker: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online